# how to get remote IP in a static class in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, clientip

such as the question,because static class not IHttpContextAccessor and HttpContext property,how to solve it?

```
public static class IPHelper
{
    //this is a wrong define
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public string GetRemoteIP()
    {
        return _accessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
    }
}
```

above,_accessor cannot define in static class and not construct. how to injection it?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by making this class static?

Comment: What will you use the IP address *for*? Outside of limited scenarios (office LAN), you'll most likely be getting the address for *some other device* on the network path between the client's machine and your server.

Comment: the MVC some controllers use a static class APIClientHelper to get data, and the APIClient require I pass the remote ip and useragent arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Use `abstract` keyword instead of `static`.